# Eager Load Pivot in nested BelongsToMany with Api Resource

Tags: php, laravel, api, pivot, many-to-many

I need your help!

I'm having problems returning pivot table information when using **ApiResources**.

If I have a model like this:

**Post.php**

```php
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Like::class)
        ->withPivot(['points']) // I want this in my PostResource::collection !
}
```

When defining its Resources:

**LikeResource.php**

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'like_field' => $this->like_field
    ];
}
```

**PostResource.php**

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [ 
        'title' => $this->title,
        'likes' => LikeResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('likes'))
    ];
}
```

Then in **PostController.php**

```php
return PostResource::collection(Post::with('likes')->get())
```

It will return something like this:

**Controller Response**

```
[
    {
        'title' => 'Post 1'
        'likes' => [
            {
                'like_field' => 'Test'
            },
            {
                'like_field' => 'Test 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'title' => 'Post 2',
        ...
    }
]
```

The problem is, using that `LikeResource::collection()` it does not appends pivot information. How could I add **'points'** of the pivot table when defining that **PostResource**??

Thats all,
Thx!

**Solution**

Well, simply reading a bit in [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships), to return pivot information you just has to use the method `$this->whenPivotLoaded()`

So, the **PostResource** becomes:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [ 
        'title' => $this->title,
        'likes' => LikeResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('likes')),
        'like_post' => $this->whenPivotLoaded('like_post', function() {
            return $this->pivot->like_field;
        })
    ];
}
```